# How to update js build process to fix "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: babeljs, vite, svelte, capacitor, apple-sign-in

I am having an easily reproducible error with the npm library `@capacitor-community/apple-sign-in`.

You can reproduce by running:

```
npm create svelte@latest my-app
cd my-app
npm install
npm i @capacitor-community/apple-sign-in
```

Then add usage of `@capacitor-community/apple-sign-in` such as in `src/routes/Header.svelte`.

Then, `npm run build` will reproduce the failure.

The error is `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

This can also be reproduced by cloning my [demo repo](https://github.com/johnpc/svelete-siwa-capacitor-demo) and `npm run build`.

The plugin seems to not have this issue with `create-react-app` apps, so it seems to be an issue with how the build is happening for default svelte apps.

I am guessing this can be fixed using babel, esbuild, or vite features, so I am reaching out to stack overflow hoping to find a workaround.

I've also created this GitHub issue: https://github.com/capacitor-community/apple-sign-in/issues/108